# Subgroup of matrices is isomorphic to a given semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Let $K$ be a field and
$$G :=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & d
\end{pmatrix}\,: a,d \in K^*, b \in K\right\} \subset GL_2(K).$$ I want to show that $G$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product $K \rtimes (K^* \times K^*).$
I need to find two subgroups $G_1, G_2$ in $G$ having trivial intersection and one of them being normal, such that $G = G_1G_2.$

Finding the appropriate homomorphism is also not difficult. What I do get for $G_1, G_2$ is subgroups consisting of $2\times 2$ matrices. But I do not recognize such subgroups while looking at the given semidirect product.
In fact, the field $K$ consists of scalors, i.e. $1 \times 1$ matrices and $K^* \times K^*$ of $1 \times 2$ matrices which I do not see how to consider them as subgroups of $G$.

How should I proceed?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: For $d=1$ we obtain the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) ${\rm Aff}(K)\cong K\rtimes K^*$ as described in the wikipedia article. Now consider $d\in GL_1(K)=K^*$.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand that.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the content of that wikipedia link. Is there some other way to explain that $G$ is isomorphic to $K \rtimes (K^* \times K^*) ?$

Comment: You could use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618381/let-phig-to-h-be-a-surjective-hom-of-groups-let-sigmah-to-g-phi-sigma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the two subgroups be
$$G_1=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1&b\\&1\end{pmatrix}\middle| b\in K\right\}\ \text{ and }\ G_2=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a&\\&d\end{pmatrix}\middle| a,d\in K^*\right\}.$$
It is easy to see that....(1) $G_1$ is normal in $G$, (2) $G_1\cap G_2=\{I\}$, (3) $G_1G_2=G$. Moreover, the following maps
$$\varphi_1\colon G_1\rightarrow K; \begin{pmatrix} 1&b\\&1\end{pmatrix}\mapsto b\ \text{ and }\ \varphi_2\colon G_2\rightarrow K^*\times K^*; \begin{pmatrix} a&\\&d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto (a,d)$$
can be seen to be isomorphisms of groups. This would clarify the problem.